# Is $TREE(4)$ bigger than $TREE(3)$

Tags: number-theory, trees

I've recently heard about the [enormous number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem#TREE(3)) $TREE(3)$ in a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3P6DWAwwViU), and I was wondering if $TREE(4)$ would be bigger?

Comment: what does TREE(n) mean

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3P6DWAwwViU

Comment: I mean to say, surely trees with 4 labels contain trees with 3 labels

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: This site has a policy of not answering questions that do not contain an attempt at an answer, and we also like the questions to be immediately clear and not contain phrases like “thanks in advance” at the end. The reason we require an attempt at an answer is to discourage homework questions, and the reason introductory and thank you phrases are not preferred, is that another person Googling your same question, should be able to recognise it without having to filter though phrases like these.

Comment: @LukeSequeira because TREE is not a commonly talked about function, so it's annoying to have to look it up, and because a [quick search of what TREE is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_tree_theorem#TREE(3)) makes the answer to your question pretty clear.

Comment: @user400188 I agree

Comment: If you would have googled the TREE-function you would have immediately found out that it is strictly increasing.

Comment: The YouTube channel "Numberphile" has [a video about Tree(3)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3P6DWAwwViU).

Comment: @Peter What do you think about the closure? Personally I think it is a bit extreme. The question no longer lacks details or clarity. It's very clear that the asker just wants to know if Tree(4) is bigger than 3, so it doesn't fit into the details/clarity section of the closure guidelines outlined here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: @user400188 The author could have added for example, how TREE(n) is defined (Kruskals theorem). Two links are not the kind of context expected here. I agree that the question is clear. The answer is so short that I would have formulated it as a comment, but other users might have another opinion concerning this.

Comment: I do not know this video, so I cannot judge, but videos tend to lack of necessary details. Therefore , I prefer reading articles. Only exception : A fascinating visualization of the Mandelbrod-set , this was a superb video , a "journey" by zooming into the picture.

Comment: This is obviously not a homework question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is enormously larger.  People reference $TREE(3)$ because it is already huge, but the function is monotonically increasing.